# jquery animation in joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla

I am trying to create a very simple slide down menu in Joomla 3.0. The slideDown and fadeOut functions are apparently not running - when I hover over the list item the sublist appears/disappears without animating. Using jquery 2.0.0, easing 1.3.

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">List A</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sublist A</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sublist Aa</a>
        </li>
    </ul></li>
<li><a href="#">List B</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sublist B</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sublist Bb</a>
        </li>           
    </ul></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function(){

var mainLi = $j('#main_nav ul li');

mainLi
.find('ul')
.hide()
.end()
.hover(function () {

    $j(this).find('> ul').stop(true, true).slideDown('slow');

}, function() {

    $j(this).find('> ul').stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast');     

});

});
```

Comment: Why don't you use bootstrap for this? It's in-built in Joomla

Comment: Dasun, can you link me to the relevant page?

Comment: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: i've gone through the documentation but didn't find anything on sliding/animating. Anyway is there something wrong with what I wrote above?

Comment: I'm with Dasun.  Build the menu in Bootstrap standards for whatever menu you're working with then implement the Dropdown JS (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns).  It doesn't animate out of the box, but you should be able to extend the JS events to fade in/out.